# How to accept zip files with Python file upload

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 to accept a file upload. The system works well in all test cases I have used except for compressed files containing more than one file.

I can replicate the issue with this:

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="processForm.py">
Upload file:<input id="userfile" name="userfile" type="file">
<input name="submit" value="Submit" type="submit">
</form>
```

submitting to this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3

print("Content-type: text/html\n")

import cgi
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
fileitem=form['userfile']
if fileitem.filename:
    fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
    open('files/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
        message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
    else:
        print('no fileitem.filename')
```

and attempting to send a .zip file containing two text files.

The error is on the form = cgi.FieldStorage() line as follows:

```
python3.3/cgi.py in __init__(self=FieldStorage(None, None, []), fp=None, headers={'content-length': '1875', 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------19416681558887788815658698'}, outerboundary=b'', environ=environ({'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '...late', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}), keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0, limit=None, encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')

cgi.py in read_multi(self=FieldStorage('userfile', 'signalFreqNov14-3c.txt.zip', None), environ=environ({'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '...late', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.5'}), keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0)

         if not valid_boundary(ib):
             raise ValueError('Invalid boundary in multipart form: %r' % (ib,))
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `application/zip`  MIME type?

Comment: With that file exactly or any zip files?

Comment: yes this occurs with any zip file that contains more than one file.

If I change the form to enctype="application/zip", then how do I get the file data?

            fileitem=form['userfile']
            if fileitem.filename:
                fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
                print('files/' + fn+'was uploaded')
                open('files/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
                message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
            else:
                print('no fileitem.filename')

always goes to the else case?